# how to iterate arrays in bash

Tags: arrays, bash

I have a number of arays and want to take each and check it's lenght.

```
#!/bin/bash

arr1=(1 2 3 4)
arr2=(foo)
arrN=(1 2 3 4 a b c d)
for arr in $arr1 $arr2 $arrN
do
        echo "${#arr[@]}" # $arr1 must be 4, right? Wrong.
        if [ ${#arr[@]} == 1 ]
        then echo "short"
        elif [ ${#arr[@]} >= 4 ]
        then echo "long"
        else echo "so so"
        fi
done
```

But i'm getting output that i did not expect.

```
kusayu@laptop:~$ ./test.sh
1
short
1
short
1
short
```

I think i understand why is it working like that, but have no idea, how to fix it.

Comment: also, `$arr == ${arr1[0]}`

But how do i put ann `$arr1` into `$arr` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash does not support multi dimensional arrays.

Hence `for arr in $arr1 $arr2 $arrN` will not work.

Following code will work:

```
arr1=(1 2 3 4)
echo "${#arr1[@]}" # $arr1 is 4
```

You could write a function returning the array length (and/or printing the output you want):

```
function myArrLen {
        arr=("$@")
        echo "${#arr[@]}"
        echo "Some other stuff you want to do.."
    }

arrA=(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
arrB=(1, 2, 3)

myArrLen "${arrA[@]}"
myArrLen "${arrB[@]}"
```

Comment: But is there any way to iterate it? Like, if i have a really big number of arrays, how i can check all of them?

Comment: You could write a function which siuts your needs. I've added an example to my answer.